# Object selected from list reads [object Object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm developing a web game in JavaScript and I have a few arrays of objects. For some reason, I'm experiencing this problem: When I randomly select an object from an array:

```js
function Weapon(name, type, ranged, hitChance, rarity){
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.ranged = ranged;
  this.hitChance = hitChance;
}

var weapons = [
  new Weapon("Dagger", "weapon", false, 100, 3),
  new Weapon("Katana", "weapon", false, 100, 2),
  new Weapon("Throwing Dagger", "weapon", true, 60, 2),
  new Weapon("Crossbow", "weapon", true, 75, 3),
  new Weapon("Grenade", "weapon", true, 85, 1),
  new Weapon("Molotov", "weapon", true, 95, 1),
  new Weapon("Axe", "weapon", false, 80, 3),
  new Weapon("Hammer", "weapon", false, 60, 3),
  new Weapon("Handgun", "weapon", true, 90, 1),
  new Weapon("Hatchet", "weapon", false, 80, 2),
  new Weapon("Switchblade", "weapon", false, 70, 2),
  new Weapon("Fishing Knife", "weapon", false, 75, 2),
  new Weapon("Satchel Charge", "weapon", false, 90, 1)
];
var itemToGive = weapons[Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons.length)];
//Returns [object Object]
```

For some reason `itemToGive` is equal to `[object Object]`.

I have heard that JavaScript does not keep track of objects to prevent lag or something along those lines. How can I get the variable to just read as one of the objects?

**EDIT:** Now it is returning undefined, not [object Object]

Comment: what specifically are you doing that makes you think it `Returns [object Object]` ?

Comment: @Oliver where are you actually returning the value of `itemToGive`? When I run your code and then run `console.log(itemToGive)` it returns one of the weapons from your list with all its properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine and the variable `itemToGive` is the object you think it should be. `[object object]` is just some problem you're experiencing with string conversion. Run the snippet below

```js
function Weapon(name, type, ranged, hitChance, rarity){
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.ranged = ranged;
  this.hitChance = hitChance;
}

var weapons = [
  new Weapon("Dagger", "weapon", false, 100, 3),
  new Weapon("Katana", "weapon", false, 100, 2),
  new Weapon("Throwing Dagger", "weapon", true, 60, 2),
  new Weapon("Crossbow", "weapon", true, 75, 3),
  new Weapon("Grenade", "weapon", true, 85, 1),
  new Weapon("Molotov", "weapon", true, 95, 1),
  new Weapon("Axe", "weapon", false, 80, 3),
  new Weapon("Hammer", "weapon", false, 60, 3),
  new Weapon("Handgun", "weapon", true, 90, 1),
  new Weapon("Hatchet", "weapon", false, 80, 2),
  new Weapon("Switchblade", "weapon", false, 70, 2),
  new Weapon("Fishing Knife", "weapon", false, 75, 2),
  new Weapon("Satchel Charge", "weapon", false, 90, 1)
];
var itemToGive = weapons[Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons.length)];

console.log(itemToGive);
```

Answer (score 1):

When I evaluate `Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons.length)` using your code I get `2`, so the problem lies in your `items` array. `items[2]` must be equal to `[object Object]`.

TKoL pointed out that `items` was most likely meant to be `weapons`, so I've changed it my example below. If in fact you do have an `items` array as well (which should match the length of `weapons`), please post the details of that.

If you try to concatenate an object like `The item to give is ${itemToGive}` or `"The item to give is " + itemToGive`, either of those will always output `[object Object]` for the value of `itemToGive`. Instead, you will need to pull a specific property from that object to use.

If you are only trying to console log this currently for internal use while developing use a comma instead of concatenating:

**NOT THIS:** `console.log("The item to give is " + itemToGive);`

**✅ THIS:** `console.log("The item to give is", itemToGive);`

See here below:

```js
function Weapon(name, type, ranged, hitChance, rarity){
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
  this.ranged = ranged;
  this.hitChance = hitChance;
}

var weapons = [
  new Weapon("Dagger", "weapon", false, 100, 3),
  new Weapon("Katana", "weapon", false, 100, 2),
  new Weapon("Throwing Dagger", "weapon", true, 60, 2),
  new Weapon("Crossbow", "weapon", true, 75, 3),
  new Weapon("Grenade", "weapon", true, 85, 1),
  new Weapon("Molotov", "weapon", true, 95, 1),
  new Weapon("Axe", "weapon", false, 80, 3),
  new Weapon("Hammer", "weapon", false, 60, 3),
  new Weapon("Handgun", "weapon", true, 90, 1),
  new Weapon("Hatchet", "weapon", false, 80, 2),
  new Weapon("Switchblade", "weapon", false, 70, 2),
  new Weapon("Fishing Knife", "weapon", false, 75, 2),
  new Weapon("Satchel Charge", "weapon", false, 90, 1)
];
var itemToGive = weapons[Math.floor(Math.random() * weapons.length)];

// INCORRECT
console.log("The item to give is " + itemToGive);

// CORRECT
console.log("The item to give is", itemToGive);
```

Comment: I think, but I'm not 100% certain, that `items` is actually supposed to say `weapons`.

Comment: @TKoL yes, I think you are correct. I just updated my answer to reflect the same. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah that was my bad sorry